# Delete database through PgAdminIII

Tags: pgadmin

I am accidentally create a database with name "" through NET/Npgsql.
Now I try to delete that database (contain 3 tables) through PgAdminIII by selecting entry, right click and choose delete/drop but I get error:

> ERROR: Syntax error at or near ";"

How to get rid of that and delete "" database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this command:

**DROP DATABASE """""";**